# How to discard cropped text from a PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I need to crop a pdf to extract some specific information in that pdf document. Is there a way that I can crop a pdf and only preserve the text inside the cropped area, and discard all the other text outside the cropped area?

I have tried using pyPdf to crop it using the following code.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

with open("in.pdf", "rb") as in_f:
    input1 = PdfFileReader(in_f)
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    numPages = input1.getNumPages()
    print "document has %s pages." % numPages

    for i in range(numPages):
        page = input1.getPage(i)
        print page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y()
        page.trimBox.lowerLeft = (25, 25)
        page.trimBox.upperRight = (225, 225)
        page.cropBox.lowerLeft = (50, 50)
        page.cropBox.upperRight = (200, 200)
        output.addPage(page)

    with open("out.pdf", "wb") as out_f:
        output.write(out_f)
```

The pdf itself gets cropped, but all the text of the uncropped pdf is still preserved. If I copy all the content of the new PDF, even the cropped (invisible) text is also copied.

Comment: can you provide the test pdf ? :D

Comment: but if my understanding is correct you cant delete the text data directly with cropping the pdf, the invisible content is still avaible in the data stream.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. The PDF I'm using can be found here http://www.update.uu.se/~jolkkonen/pdf/CRC_TD.pdf

Answer (score 0):

After i played around with your PDF and cropping i figured out thats not possible to crop and also delete `invisible` data.

Basicly what cropping does is adding `/CropBox [ 50 50 200 200 ]` element to PDF but the actual data is still remainingin the PDF.

Hint: Try to extract your data without croppping and also maybe with a lib like `pdfminer`, `ghostscript` or give `PyPDF` another try with extracting text or get context boxes.

Comment: That is correct, and it is not because of Python; that's what PDF cropping is. Some GUI tools will give a warning about it when you use the crop feature. You need a different approach, e.g. copy each page element to a new page, checking its coordinates against the crop rectangle. You may have to lose some elements that are half-in, half-out, but it should work for most text.

Comment: @alexis why copy if you can extraxt text and write new file with this content :D

Comment: The purpose of this is to isolate colums of data in the PDF. I need to parse the data from the PDF and make it into a format which is easily indexable by software. The problem is, that the blank spots in the table aren't represented by anything. So when I extract data from the PDF, I have no chance of knowing where the specific pieces of data belong in the table. I had the idea of isolating the columns of every page, so I could detect where the blank spaces are, and parse the data that way.

Comment: @Fabian, it depends what your goal is! Normally you crop PDF if you want to distribute a **PDF** file, just without the cropped-out content. If you want to extract text, cropping is the wrong approach.

Comment: @cnovrup, then you are way off course! :-)  Cropping is not the way to go. Please post a **new** question and ask about doing what you wrote in the comment. (Do give more detail about "isolating columns of data"). I believe there are PDF libraries that can give you a structured table, for example.

Comment: I see what you mean. It seems like I've taken a much more difficult approach than it needed to be. I'll look into some of those libraries. Do you know any, that might work? In any case, thanks! :)